# Losing row id in tableview before passing data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a Navigation controller embedded to a VC called UserDashboardVC. I then have a menu VC and the one option opens another VC with a tableview, ManageAccountVC. When I select the table row I would like it to unwind and populate the data on the UserDashboardVC.

I'm struggling to pass the data back to the UserDashboardVC using unwind segue from ManageAccountVC.

In my UserDashboardVC (root) I have my unwind segue code:

```
@IBAction func unwindUserDashboardVC(_ unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    userCompanyLabel.text   = PassCompanyOffice}
```

In my ManageAccountVC the tableview cell has been connected to Exit unwindUserDashboardVC, this works, when I click on the cell I unwind to UserDashboardVC. I have a function in ManageAccountVC to get the row selected:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    PassCompanyOffice = userAccountArray[indexPath.row].companyOffice!
}
```

I also have the Prepare function in ManageAccountVC which seems to trigger before I get my row value:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let ConfirmVC = segue.destination as! UserDashboardVC
        ConfirmVC.PassCompanyOffice = PassCompanyOffice
}
```

Why is my unwind segue being performed before my cell row is identified? How do I pass back my data?

Comment: Is everything in code or are you also using a storyboard? A picture of the VCs in the storyboard might be helpful to establish context.

Comment: Rather than unwinding the segue assign a callback closure in `ManageAccountVC` which is called in `viewDidDisappear` and passes the data. Unwinding is needed only if the controllers are not directly related to each other.

Comment: @TommieC. I'm using Storyboards

Comment: @vadian will this work going back two VCs? 
(1) UserDashboardVC > (2) UserMenuVC > (3) ManageAccountVC 
Tableview is on 3 and need to pass data to 1

Comment: Then unwind segue is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create a class member to hold the selected row and assign that in willSelectRow for the tableview. Then pickup the value in the prepare for Segue or the unwind segue in this case. Put a breakpoint in the unwind segue to determine the state of the selected row variable before using it.

### Manual Segue

To separate the cell click action from the segue you will need to remove the exit segue that you made from the tableview cell to the exit.

Then create a manual segue from the view controller to the exit icon. Give that segue an identifier and then call the performSegue with identifier (using the exitSegueIdentifier)

This way you separate the two actions. You can click on the table without exiting. In your code base you can decide when you want to call the performSegue and actually close the VC using the manual exit segue.

Comment: Got it. I'll clarify in my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As @Tommie C. mentioned, my issue was with the TableViewCell that was linked to the Storyboard Exit. I removed that segue and added a manual Exit seguel by doing this:

[image]

Make sure the above is made identifiable, in this case it is "loadDashboardSegue". The Prepare function has the segue identifier name "loadDashboardSegue":

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "loadDashboardSegue" {
        let ConfirmVC = segue.destination as! UserDashboardVC
        ConfirmVC.PassCompanyOffice = PassCompanyOffice
    }
}
```

Lastly, you action the segue manually in the tableview row select:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    PassCompanyOffice = userAccountArray[indexPath.row].companyOffice
    performSegue(withIdentifier:"loadDashboardSegue", sender: self)
}
```